# How to display multiple student name in zii.widgets.grid.CGridView from database in admin page?

Tags: php, yii

```
<?php 
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'tasks-grid',
'dataProvider' => $model->search($tmp),
'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-striped table-hover table-bordered',
'filter' => $model,
'columns' => array(
'task_id',
array('header' => 'Sr. No.',
'value' => '$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + ($row+1)', 'id' => 'colour', 'filter' => 'Search By :'),
array('name' => 'pm_id',
'value' => '$data->project1->project'),
'task_title',
'assigned_to',
'priority',
'status',
?>
```

I want to display assigned_to multiple student names like this format on gideView, for example:

> Rahul,Nikesh,Omkar.

but it display like this eg Rahul (it displays only one name but in my database table 1,27,26 (student ids) on assigned_to columns).

```
'task_title',
'assigned_to',
'priority',
'status'
```

This is my four column in database table.

Comment: You need to do better than that. Please format your question with proper text and code so people can understand :)

Comment: So assigned_to contains a CSV of student ids? How does the mapping of those ids to the student names happen now? Based on your current code it should just display those ids instead of 1 student name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your relation assigned_to is a HAS_MANY or MANY_MANY relation you could do something like:

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'tasks-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search($tmp),
    'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-striped table-hover table-bordered',
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        'task_id',
        array('header' => 'Sr. No.',
            'value' => '$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + ($row+1)', 'id' => 'colour', 'filter' => 'Search By :'),
        array('name' => 'pm_id',
            'value' => '$data->project1->project'),
        'task_title',
        array(
            'name'=>'assigned_to',
            'value'=>'implode(",", array_values(CHtml::listData($data->assigned_to)))'
        ),
        'priority',
        'status',
    )
));
```